# MongoDb Aggregation (SQL UNION style)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, union

I need some help/advice on how to replicate some SQL behaviour in MongoDB.
Specifically, given this collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("577ebc0660084921141a7857"),
  "tournament" : "Wimbledon",
  "player1" : "Agassi",
  "player2" : "Lendl",
  "sets" : [{
      "score1" : 6,
      "score2" : 4,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }, {
      "score1" : 7,
      "score2" : 6,
      "tiebreak" : true
    }, {
      "score1" : 7,
      "score2" : 6,
      "tiebreak" : true
    }]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("577ebc3560084921141a7858"),
  "tournament" : "Wimbledon",
  "player1" : "Ivanisevic",
  "player2" : "McEnroe",
  "sets" : [{
      "score1" : 4,
      "score2" : 6,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }, {
      "score1" : 3,
      "score2" : 6,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }, {
      "score1" : 6,
      "score2" : 4,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("577ebc7560084921141a7859"),
  "tournament" : "Roland Garros",
  "player1" : "Navratilova",
  "player2" : "Graf",
  "sets" : [{
      "score1" : 5,
      "score2" : 7,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }, {
      "score1" : 6,
      "score2" : 3,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }, {
      "score1" : 7,
      "score2" : 7,
      "tiebreak" : true
    }, {
      "score1" : 7,
      "score2" : 5,
      "tiebreak" : false
    }]
}
```

And these two distinct aggregations:

**1) Aggregation ALFA**: this aggregation is purposely strange, in the sense that it is designed to find all matches where **at least 1 tiebreak is true** but **only show sets where tiebreak is false**. Please don't consider the logic of it, it is crafted to allow full freedom to the user.

```
{
    $match: {
        "tournament": "Wimbledon",
        "sets.tiebreak": true
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "tournament": 1,
        "player1": 1,
        "sets": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$sets",
                as: "set",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$set.tiebreak", false]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Aggregation BETA**: this aggregation is purposely strange, in the sense that it is designed to find all matches where **at least 1 tiebreak is false** but **only show sets where tiebreak is true**. Please don't consider the logic of it, it is crafted to allow full freedom to the user. Please note that **player1** is hidden from the results.

```
{
    $match: {
        "tournament": "Roland Garros",
        "sets.tiebreak": false
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "tournament": 1,
        "sets": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$sets",
                as: "set",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$set.tiebreak", true]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose that these two aggregations purpose is to delimit what part of the database a user can see, in the sense that those two queries delimit all the documents (and details) that are visible to the user. This is similar to 2 sql views that user has rights to access.

**I need/want to try to rewrite the previous distinct aggregations in only one. Can this be achieved?**

It is mandatory to keep all restriction that were set in Aggregation A & B, without loosing any control on data and without leaking and data that was not available in query A or B.

Specifically, matches in Wimbledon can only be seen if they had at least one set which ended with a tiebreak. Player1 field CAN be seen. Single sets must be hidden if they did not end with a tiebreak and hidden otherwise. *If needed, it is acceptable, but not desirable, to not see player1 at all.*

Conversely, matches in Roland Garros can be seen only if they had at least one set which ended without a tie break. Player1 field MUST be hidden. Single sets must be seen if they ended with a tiebreak and hidden otherwise.

Again, the purpose is to UNION the two aggregations while keeping the limits imposed by the two aggregations.

MongoDB is version 3.5, can be upgraded to unstable releases if needed.

Comment: it would be an extra to use Regular Expressions in textual filters. Performance oriented strategies are a plus, but not mandatory.

Comment: it seems to me that you are pulling data from a single collection, so to get both types of data try $or. UNION typically pulls from different tables with similar columns.

Comment: Yes, I am pulling from the same collection... but unfortunately, the point is not in the $match stage (using $or...) but the $project stage which seems impossible/too difficult to me... Thanks anyways!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it seems to me that you do have to use $or in the $match phase and a more sophisticated $filter in $project. Alternatively, why not output using $out to the same collection. Then that collection will have exactly the data that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you again tiramisu, unfortunately again this is not an option.
I was not totally clear in my question (a little on purpose, actually...) that this has to be a "live" query, since I cannot afford to print out "stale data". 

The logic of the app is that "User Admin" creates queries A & B and assigns them separately to "User normal". Eventually "User normal" will want to see the two queries together.

In a new comment I'll add the query I've come to so far... which still is not perfectly created... and is keen to data leaks... 

I need help in the "$project" stage...

Comment: Pseudo code:

$match: {
        $or: [
               { conditions from query A},
               { conditions from query B}
},

$project: {
"tournament": (project_a == true && project_b == true) ? true : false,
"player1": (project_a == true && project_b == true) ? true : false,
"sets": {
$filter: {
input: "$sets",
as: "set",
cond: {
$or: [
{ 
$and: [match_conditions_A, project_condition_A]
},
{ 
$and: [match_conditions_B, project_condition_B]
}
]}}}}

The point in this pseudocode is that in the "$project" stage I cannot use "sets.tiebreak" as one of match_conditions_A.

Comment: @Tiramisu, too bad if you $out to the same collection, the second aggregation overwrites the first aggregation results...

Comment: I think I did it.. Coudl someone confirm I am right? Thanks.  http://pastebin.com/CV4M7pDh

Comment: I think that does it. I'm sorry about the two $out's suggestion. I learned something too!

Comment: In case a *Wimbledon* doc has *all* `true` tibreaks, or *Roland Garros* has *all* `false` tiebreaks response will end up with those docs with empty sets .
is this desired?

Answer (score 0):

here's my two cents for the issue:
if you wish to avoid empty sets when

- a "*Wimbledon*" doc has **all** `true` tibreaks,
- or "*Roland Garros*" has **all** `false` tiebreaks

you may reshape the query:

```
...
 {
   $and: [{
     "sets.tiebreak": true,
   }, {
     "sets.tiebreak": false
   }],
   $or: [{
     "tournament": "Wimbledon"
   }, {
     "tournament": "Roland Garros"
   }]
 }
...
```

and use it in:

- aggregate pipeline http://pastebin.com/cM6mNsuC
- mapReduce (if performance is no a big issue..) http://pastebin.com/MShihSQL

Comment: Hard to tell which one is the correct behaviour, since this was just a test. The point of this was to mimic an SQL UNION. Since "Aggregation ALFA/BETA" would return empty sets, I *think* my query is still the most correct, but your note points to a more than correct annotation.

It would be nice to benchmark the two different approaches. I think more stages = more time, but it could also be that a *hard* projection might consume even more time than a list of matches/unwinds/matches... Will investigate...

Comment: I will not mark your answer as the correct one for the reasons in the previous comment, but it is certainly a valid approach.